# Getting “No unapply or unapplySeq function found” exception in Scala Play application

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am trying a web application with Scala Play 2, Slick 3 and PostgreSQL. My purpose to return JSON from controller.

These are the Dependencies -

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.0",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "1.0.1",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "1.0.1",
    specs2 % Test
)
```

This is my Model -

```
package models

import play.api.libs.json.Json
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import scala.concurrent.Future

case class User(id: String, name: String)

object Users extends ModelInit {
    class UserModel(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {
        def id = column[String]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
        def email = column[String]("EMAIL")
        def * = (id, email) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
    }

    lazy val users = TableQuery[UserModel]
    implicit val userFormat = Json.format[UserModel]

    def all = {
        db.run(users.result)
    }

    def create(user: User): Future[Int] = {
        db.run(users += user)
    }

    def getById(name: String) = {
        val selectQuery = users.map(_.id)
        val selectAction = selectQuery.result
        db.run(selectAction)
   }
}
```

This is my Controller -

```
package controllers

import models.Users
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
import play.api.libs.json._

class Application extends Controller {
    def index = Action {
        Users.all.map(user => println(Json.toJson(user)))
        Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
    }
}
```

Currently I am getting "No unapply or unapplySeq function found" exception. Here is the full stacktrace -

```
play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[No unapply or unapplySeq function found]
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
        at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:377) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compile(PlayReload.scala:17) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$2.apply(PlayRun.scala:61) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$2.apply(PlayRun.scala:61) ~[na:na]
        at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anonfun$reload$1.apply(Reloader.scala:323) ~[na:na]
        at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anon$3.run(Reloader.scala:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
        at play.runsupport.Reloader$.play$runsupport$Reloader$$withReloaderContextClassLoader(Reloader.scala:39) ~[na:na]
        at play.runsupport.Reloader.reload(Reloader.scala:321) ~[na:na]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:113) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
```

Comment: This is a compilation error, not a runtime exception. This stack trace is not helpful to figuring out what your problem is. You should find the full compilation error your logs and that should give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

Moving Json formatter to controller solved the issue.

My current Model -

```
package models

import play.api.libs.json.Json
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import scala.concurrent.Future

case class User(id: String, name: String)

object Users extends ModelInit {
    class UserModel(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {
        def id = column[String]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
        def email = column[String]("EMAIL")
        def * = (id, email) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
    }

    lazy val users = TableQuery[UserModel]

    def all = {
        db.run(users.result)
    }

    def create(user: User): Future[Int] = {
        db.run(users += user)
    }

    def getById(name: String) = {
        val selectQuery = users.map(_.id)
        val selectAction = selectQuery.result
        db.run(selectAction)
   }
}
```

And current Controller -

```
package controllers

import models.Users
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
import play.api.libs.json._

class Application extends Controller {
    def index = Action {
        implicit val userFormat = Json.format[UserModel]
        Users.all.map(user => println(Json.toJson(user)))
        Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
    }
}
```